# How to write this long equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{E}_{tot}=q\cdot k_{b}\cdot \dfrac{r}{r^3}\left\lgroup
\dfrac{\hat{r}-\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot cos (\theta)\right)^{3/2}}-\dfrac{\hat{r}+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\cdot\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot cos(\theta)\right)^{3/2}}
\right\rgroup

\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full compilable code?

Answer (score 7):

This is a case for `multline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\vec{E}_{\mathrm{tot}}=
  q\cdot k_{b}\cdot \dfrac{r}{r^3}
  \left\lgroup
    \frac{\hat{r}-\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}
         {\biggl(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2-
                   \left(\dfrac{d}{r}\right)\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot\cos(\theta)
          \biggr)^{3/2}}
  \right.
  \\
  \left.
    {}-
    \frac{\hat{r}+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}
         {\biggl(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2+
                   \left(\dfrac{d}{r}\right)\cdot\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot\cos(\theta)
          \biggr)^{3/2}}
  \right\rgroup
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

I changed a couple of `\left`-`\right` pairs so to keep the outer parentheses a bit smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

First off: [Don't use `eqnarray`. Not now. Not ever.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001)

Second, by getting rid of all `\cdot` directives and replacing most `\left` and `\right` directives with smaller sizing opeators `\Big` and `\bigg`), and assuming normal-width margins, it's easily possible to write the entire equation on a single line.

Separately, you may want to look into not using displaymath-mode fractional notation. The result look is shown in the second equation of the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose page margins suitable
\begin{document}

\[
\vec{E}_{\mathrm{tot}}=q k_{b}^{} \frac{r}{r^3}
\left(
 \ddfrac{\hat{r}-\Bigl(\frac{d}{2r}\Bigr)\hat{d}}{%
 \biggl(1+\Bigl(\frac{d}{2r}\Bigr)^{\!2}
    -\Bigl(\frac{d}{r}\Bigr)\hat{r}\hat{d}\cos(\theta)\biggr)^{\!3/2}}
-\ddfrac{\hat{r}+\Bigl(\frac{d}{2r}\Bigr)\hat{d}}{%
 \biggl(1+\Bigl(\frac{d}{2r}\Bigr)^{\!2}
    +\Bigl(\frac{d}{r}\Bigr)\hat{r}\hat{d}\cos(\theta)\biggr)^{\!3/2}}
\right)
\]

\bigskip
%% and now without displaystyle fractions
\[
\vec{E}_{\mathrm{tot}}=q k_{b}^{} \tfrac{r}{r^{3\mathstrut}}
\mleft[
 \dfrac{\hat{r}-\frac{d}{2r}\hat{d}}{%
 \bigl[1+\frac{d^2}{4r^{2\mathstrut}}
    -\frac{d}{r}\hat{r}\hat{d}\cos(\theta)\bigr]^{3/2}}
-\dfrac{\hat{r}+\frac{d}{2r}\hat{d}}{%
 \bigl[1+\frac{d^2}{4r^{2\mathstrut}}
    +\frac{d}{r}\hat{r}\hat{d}\cos(\theta)\bigr]^{3/2}}
\mright]
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since it is one equation, I would rather use the `multline`(*) environment in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  \vec{E}_{tot} = q\cdot k_{b}\cdot \dfrac{r}{r^3}\left\lgroup
  \dfrac{\hat{r}-\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+
  \left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\hat{r}
  \cdot\hat{d}\cdot \cos (\theta)\right)^{3/2}}\right.\\
  - \left.\dfrac{\hat{r}+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}
  {\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2
  +\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\cdot\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot \cos(\theta)
  \right)^{3/2}}\right\rgroup
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your code is incorrect, since you use a blank line just before the end of `eqnarray*`. Just remove that, then it works.

[image: long equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{E}_{tot}=q\cdot k_{b}\cdot \dfrac{r}{r^3}\left\lgroup
\dfrac{\hat{r}-\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot cos (\theta)\right)^{3/2}}-\dfrac{\hat{r}+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\cdot\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot cos(\theta)\right)^{3/2}}
\right\rgroup
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* As alsways it is a bad idea to use `eqnarray*` if there are such great environments as, f.i., `align*`, which could btw help you break those equations.

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\vec{E}_{tot}&=q\cdot k_{b}\cdot \dfrac{r}{r^3}\left\lgroup
\dfrac{\hat{r}-\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot \cos (\theta)\right)^{3/2}}\right.\\
&- \left.\dfrac{\hat{r}+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)\hat{d}}{\left(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2\cdot r}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{d}{ r}\right)\cdot\hat{r}\cdot\hat{d}\cdot \cos(\theta)\right)^{3/2}}\right\rgroup
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `&=` not `=&` (see the (no) space around the =

Answer (score 2):

It can perfectly fit in a single line, if you remove the `\cdot`s, which I think are unnecessary, and a number of useless parentheses. Unrelated to the problem at hand, I replaced `\vec`, which isn't so nice with capital letters, with `\vv` from `esvect`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \vv*{E}{\text{tot}} =q k_{b}\, \frac{r}{r^3}\mkern-6mu%
 \left\lgroup
\frac{\hat{r}-\dfrac{d}{2 r}\,\hat{d}}{\biggl(1+\biggl(\dfrac{d}{2 r}\biggr)^{\!2}\!-\dfrac{d}{ r}\,\hat{r}\hat{d}\,\cos \theta\biggr)^{\!\tfrac{3}{2}}}%
 -\frac{\hat{r}+ \dfrac{d}{2 r}\,\hat{d}}{\biggl(1+\left(\dfrac{d}{2 r}\right)^{\!2}\!+\dfrac{d}{ r}\,\hat{r}\hat{d}\, \cos \theta \biggr)^{\!\tfrac{3}{2}}}
\right\rgroup
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The use of `\!` in `\biggr)^{\!2}` makes a big difference.  IMO it *improves* the output too, by more closely associating the power with the bracket